# Cannot add a second comment on Android App

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

App version: 1.0.31
Device: Nexus 7
Problem: When I comment on an answer the "Add Comment" button disappears. It doesn't reappear if I refresh the question. I would have to close out of the question and open it back up to add another comment.

Comment: Testing for 1st comment from Nexus 4, Android 4.4.2, App 1.0.31.

Comment: I can comment again without any problem... seems like there is different behavior between phone and tablet, or other specific case.

Comment: Maybe it only happens on an answer? It does seem to work here. It wasn't working for me when i was adding a comment to my own answer on SO

Comment: Ok, confirm repro'd only on answer after commenting it once.

Comment: Hmm...wasn't able to reproduce on 4.4 HTC One.

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.0.82 (beta)<sup>or probably since [v1.0.50](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248519/241919) when Q&A page was redone</sup>, it has been fixed: you can comment on any answers multiple times, the "Add comment" button is still there after posting a comment.

[image: no comment] [image: posting comment] [image: after first comment]

Comment: This is a test comment