# Swiping from question to answer is broken by long lines

Tags: bug, android-app, scrolling

When viewing [this question<sup>1</sup>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26972/10619) with the Android app (on a Nexus 4 and a Lenovo tablet), I can't switch from the question to the answers by swiping from right to left. It works on all of the screen except the content of the question. In other words, the swipe works only in the areas of the title and the other areas below the username. I'm pretty sure it's caused by the lines containing long strings without spaces.

Swiping works if I scroll horizontally to the right of the question, but it takes some time to get there because the swiping is badly recognised – it doesn't scroll if I don't swipe along a perfectly horizontal line.

<sup>1: [*Encode a string for aliens that read and write English, but don't know ASCII* @ Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26972/10619)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the edit Nick Stauner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android app is now displaying the question and its answers on [the same view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239962/241919) (since v1.0.50, based on other posts on that date), replacing the question/answers tabs navigation, and thus, this bug is now obsolete (aka "fixed").