# Inconsistency between pull-to-refresh animations

Tags: feature-request, android-app

When in a question, pulling down uses the style of the latest update, like Gmail; but pulling down on, for example, the main page, shows the older "Pull down to refresh" animation

Just a minor OCD thing, doesn't need to be fixed if it can't, but a bit of consistency would be nice.

Comment: There's a bug in your profile picture! It's all wrong and flipped and stuff! Everybody panic! (Haha, yes, I know how it feels to be incredibly annoyed by even the most minor of details. +1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new question-and-answer detail view users `RecyclerView`, a new API in Android. The current implementation of this API does not work well alongside the pull to refresh library we are using everywhere else in the application. Granted, the pull to refresh that is in most places of the app is technically deprecated and the one used on the question detail view is *official* way of handling pull-to-refresh, but personally I do not like it a lot.

I'm currently waiting for Android L to be released, so the full source code of `RecyclerView` is released (it's currently in a incubation period for testing), and I can try to make it work with our older pull-to-refresh library. If this is do-able, then everywhere in the app will use the current pull-to-refresh implementation (the one that changes the action bar to display "Release to refresh" when pulling) -- if I'm not able to do this, everywhere in the application will use the new style (which is what Gmail uses too).

Until this decision can be made, I'm going to leave the app with two different pull-to-refresh implementations since the only way I could make it all match right now is by using the new official way, which I'd really rather not use everywhere.

Comment: Oh well... Thanks. Kinda sucks that they are releasing the library w/o source code... +1

Comment: @EasyasPi we're technically not supposed to be using the new APIs for anything but testing right now, but the view works *so* much better with the new API and I didn't want to sit on a bunch of code for months.