# Unable to log in using Google Account

Tags: bug, android-app

I'm using Android L on my Nexus 5 and ever since my Google Play Services updated to the latest version, I haven't been able to log in via my Google Account using the Stack Exchange app. This is the shortened stack trace:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.login.LoginActivityTask}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error
>   inflating class
>   com.android.setupwizard.navigationbar.SetupWizardNavBar$NavButton
>   ...
>   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable-v21/auth_setup_wizard_navbar_ic_back.xml from drawable
>   resource ID #0x7f020086
>   ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

[Full stack trace on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/x3qdFTTK)

[image: Screenshot]

Brings up another point - does the Stack Exchange app support Android L?

Comment: Well, the chief developer of the app wrote [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239962/152859) that he's "currently waiting for Android L to be released" (two weeks ago) so most likely it's not supported yet and that's the cause of the bug.

Comment: No repro for me on Nexus 5 running L and Google Play Services 6.1.11, maybe a new update came out that fixed it?

Comment: I'm on Nexus 5 and Google Play Services 6.1.11 - clean flash of the image and still the same problem. Odd! Logged in via FB fine, logged out and tried to log in via Google and still the same.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Sorry, looks like this may be an issue with Google Play Services on my device after all. Getting repeated exceptions when I add a secondary Google account.

Answer (score 2):

Until L is officially released we (developers) are at the mercy of Google Play Services and of Google in general.

The last update made to Google Play Services recently broke it. If I am reading the stack trace correctly they forgot to include an arrow asset that only gets used in L so it can't show the permissions dialog necessary for login.