# Two load icons simultaneously appearing in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

This [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239958/inconsistency-between-pull-to-refresh-animations) confirms that the Android app is using two different loaders since last year, but just today I've noted that, at the questions page, it is using them simultaneously. I've never noted this, so I believe this bug was recently created.

I hope the following gif is clear enough to show the issue. Also, note that the bigger loader is "freezing".

[image: Gif]

SE Android App Version: 1.0.60
My Android OS Version: 5.0.2

Still observed in version 1.0.89

Comment: Based from my observation, the bigger one (on question list) only appears when it's empty/having few entries. I agree it's still... weird, though.

Comment: Confirmed on `SE App Version 1.0.95` and `Android 8.0`