# Search bar overlaps the refresh icon

Tags: support, bug, android-app

When pulling down the question list in the Stack Exchange Android app to refresh it this visual bug happens:

[image: visual bug while refreshing]

(This is obviously not a critical bug, but could become problematic if the search bar would be larger or the refresh icon smaller, because you would not have any visual feedback that you are refreshing.)

Comment: I've also found [another error](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252750/two-load-icons-simultaneously-appearing-in-android-app) related with this pull-to-refresh animation. [Maybe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239958/inconsistency-between-pull-to-refresh-animations) they should favor the new Android RecyclerView and remove this pull-to-refresh library.

Comment: @Zanon sadly we're currently using both RecyclerView and SwipeRefreshLayout from the official support library, yet still getting weird issues like this.