# Editing posts automatically changes HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: support, status-bydesign, edits, suggested-edits, hyperlinks

## Background

I edited [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/54106) on this site and submitted for review. (I knew the edit was kinda bad, but the previous editor did the same thing and the edited was accepted  probably due to the high-rep-no-review-needed-to-edit)

---

## What happened

I was wondering did anyone accept or reject my edit, then I found out an Moderator ♦ rejected my edit. The message reads:

> Why did you remove HTTPS?

**I didn't even edited out that part!** I did not change anything about the link. However somehow `HTTPS` get changed to `HTTP` for no reason.

---

**Why does an edit maps `HTTPS` to `HTTP`? Is that a bug or an intentional feature?**

Comment: Any chance you selected a different revision in the drop down, by mistake?

Comment: I don’t think so.. I edited directly from the latest edit.

Comment: Did you click the edit link directly below the question, or did you go through the edit history (and maybe scroll down a bit first)? If you did the latter, you might have ended up accidentally reverting the latest edit by Community♦ that added the `s`.

Comment: Well, no repro for me. Maybe you have some userscript messing around with links, try to disable all of them and suggest the edit again.

Comment: @llmariKaronen I think I didn't revert the community edit.

Comment: re-tagging as a bug so developers see this, but I'm pretty certain it isn't on our end.

Comment: @TimPost Mod Shog9 has confirmed that it is a silly mistake on my end, so I'd remove the [tag:bug] tag.

Comment: Please don't add "NOTE" sections at the tops of questions once they're solved. That's not appropriate. The questions stay questions and the answers explain them. Questions should not be edited to explain the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked the server logs relevant to your edit, and reconstructed what occurred here.

- At 11:51:20 you clicked the "edit" link below [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252750/two-load-icons-simultaneously-appearing-in-android-app)

  [image: image of editor as it would've appeared to the asker]

  Note the portions of the image labeled #2 (which notes that you're editing the revision made by Community on March 20th) and #3 (which notes that the https protocol is present in the text).
- At 11:51:24 you clicked the revision drop down and selected the second revision in the list:

  [image: edit screen showing the older revision selected for editing]

  Note that you now would've seen Sha Wiz Dow Ard listed as the author of the revision being edited (#1), and http as the protocol (#2).
- At 11:51:29 you clicked the revision drop-down and re-selected the first (most recent) revision.
- At 11:51:34 you clicked the revision drop-down once more and selected the second (Sha Wiz Dow Ard) revision.
- You then proceeded to make edits to the body of the post, and submitted your changes at 11:52:34

This behavior is by design: the purpose of the revision drop-down is to allow you to choose a revision upon which to base your own edit. Under normal circumstances, you should leave it at the default (most recent) selection; changing it is liable to produce an unwanted outcome, as we saw here.

Comment: Um... You can change which version of the post you're editing?

Comment: From the full edit page (which is what suggested edits always use), yes. Alternately possible by clicking edit on a specific revision from the revision history (which gives you the same full editor, with a different revision selected by default).

Comment: I (clearly) had no clue. I found it through the revision history before you responded but I don't think I've *ever* gotten to that version of the page until today. Interesting.

Comment: @Shog9 What an silly mistake. I'll avoid it in the future. Sorry for making such a fuss.

Comment: @Catija I was pretty sure that's what happened, but OP claimed he did not touch the drop down. Well.

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce this using the latest stable versions of Chrome, Safari or Firefox. I'm very receptive to the idea that *something* changed it as you were editing, but I can't find any evidence that said something was on our end.

You indicated that you're pretty certain that you didn't inadvertently attempt to revert the edit where the https:// link was introduced, and attempting to do that would be quite deliberate, so I'm inclined to agree that's probably not what happened.

Perhaps you have some kind of user script or extension running that might explain things, or some kind of content filter? I'll leave it to a developer to put a status tag on this, but I can't manage to reproduce it.

Could there be anything else about your setup that you might have forgotten to mention? Do you perhaps live or work with a very intelligent cat?

Comment: I do have userscripts on my end, but it doesn't affect the link changing problem. **The thing is that it was a silly mistake on my end**. :/